# How do I convert a move from coordinate notation to algebraic notation?

Tags: analysis, notation, python

The following Python code gives the best move in coordinate notation:

```
import chess
import chess.engine
sfEngineTxt = "E:\Chess\Stockfish\stockfish_14_x64_modern"
sfEngine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(sfEngineTxt)
sfInfo = sfEngine.analyse(chess.Board(), chess.engine.Limit(depth=11), info=chess.engine.INFO_ALL)
moveArray = sfInfo['pv']
moveTxt1 = str(moveArray[0])
print(moveTxt1)
sfEngine.quit()
```

This outputs **e2e4**. What I want is **e4**, I.e. algebraic notation or san notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `Board.san()` which gives you the algebraic notation. You can check the docs [here](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#chess.Board.san).

You will need a Board object for it.

```
import chess

board = chess.Board()
move = chess.Move.from_uci("e2e4")
print(board.san(move))
# Output: e4
```